# Syntax error in constructor

Tags: dart

The following code

```dart
class MemberException extends ServerException {
  String message;
  MemberException(message) {
    super(message);
  }
}

class ServerException implements Exception {
  String message;
  ServerException(this.message);
}
```

produces the following (somewhat unhelpful) error message

```dart
Too few arguments in implicit super() constructor invocation in '(String) -> dynamic'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct format is:

```dart
class MemberException extends ServerException {
  String message;
  MemberException(message) : super(message) {
    // constructor body
  }
}
```

You need to initialize super before the constructor body is called.
Ref: http://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch02.html#ch02-constructors (see the part on initializers)

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was going to be a syntax error of some kind, but the error message produced by the compiler doesn't exactly help.

Comment: That kind of feedback is useful - might be worth creating an issue on http://dartbug.com and adding this example and your comment.  That way the right people will see it.